# Swift: Transfer value from one class to another or to be specific from ViewController class to NSObject

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, nsobject

How do I transfer a value from the viewDidLoad in a UIViewController to another class - NSObject.

Basically I have a MainViewController class and inside the class is a navigation bar. I wanted to access the height of the navigation bar and transfer the value to to another file/class which is -> class SettingsLauncher: NSObject.

Only way I can access the navigation Bar Height is inside viewDidLoad of the MainViewController class. This is might be the issue!

The SettingsLauncher needs to get the height value of the navigation Bar so it can display a small view right under the navigation bar.

From Code below:

The navBarHeight gets the height of the navigation bar. How can I transfer that value to my other class (SettingsLauncher)?

```
let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
let navBarHeight= self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0
let topBarHeight = statusBarHeight + navBarHeight
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a struct in the `MainViewController` class, like so:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    struct structure {
        static var topBarHeight = CGFloat()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        let navBarHeight= self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0
        structure.topBarHeight = statusBarHeight + navBarHeight
    }
}
```

Then use it to access the value from the `SettingsLauncher` object:

```
class SettingsLauncher {
    var navHeight = MainViewController.structure.topBarHeight
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in `SettingsLauncher` like `navHeight`, then

```
class SettingsLauncher {
    var navHeight: CGFloat?
}
```

In `MainViewController`,

```
class MainViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        let navBarHeight= self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height ?? 0.0
        let topBarHeight = statusBarHeight + navBarHeight

        let settings = SettingsLauncher()
        settings.navHeight = topBarHeight //navBarHeight
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, when I print the navHeight it is returning nil. Am I missing something?

Comment: where are you printing? In MainViewController or SettingsLauncher?

Comment: I am printing it out on both. It works fine from the MainViewController but from SettingsLauncher it prints out 'nil'

Comment: can you please share code snippet of SettingsLauncher class?

Comment: class SettingsLauncher: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    var navHeight = MainViewController.structure.topBarHeight    
    
    let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        return cv
    }()
    
    class SettingsLauncher {
    var navHeight: CGFloat?
}
    func showSettings() {

        let mainViewController = MainViewController()
       print(navHeight, "")